# Why argument type extending String can't be used like String

Tags: java, generics

Supposing I have a code like this

```
class B<T extends String>
{
    T f(T a){
        return a+"def";
    }
}
```

why does it give me a compile time error "error: incompatible types"? Why can't I use something that extends String like a string?

Comment: `String` is final; I'm not even sure the compiler will _let_ you write `T extends String`.

Comment: you also cant extend Integer etc. They are sacred.

Comment: But with "return a;" alone it compiles perfectly.

Comment: Just for clarity, `<T extends String>` is nonsensical. That essentially translates to `String` (For reasons @LouisWasserman mentioned). This renders the generic component of this class inert, so you might as well just write it for strings to begin with. That will fix your [other] problem as well.

Comment: It's an example from an exam, so rather a theoretical one. But I still don't see any sense in compiler letting extend String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator applied to a `String` and anything else is the `String` concatenation operator and produces a `String`.

Your return type is `T`, not `String`. `T` may (won't, but theoretically could) be any subtype of `String`. For that reason, this cannot be allowed to compile.

Similarly,

```
class Foo {}
class B<T extends Foo> {
    T f(T a) {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo {}
```

but

```
new B<Bar>().f(new Bar());
```

should have a return type of `Bar`, but would return a `Foo`. That doesn't make sense and so doesn't compile.

Comment: why would anyone need subclass of String not being String itself? why does the compiler allow it? Could you add some methods to the existing class with this pattern(something like categories in Obj-C)?

Comment: You cannot add methods to existing classes, and can't really even approximate it when the classes are final.

Comment: Thanks for that. So how would you do it in Java - add a method to String, which returns SHA1 of the String itself? Would you rather use some converter class?

Comment: @SzymonFortuna Create a utility class/method to do it, given a `String`.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Yet another difference between iOS and Android development.